# Access Spark SQL Dataframes via Dropwizard?

Tags: java, apache-spark, jersey, dropwizard, parquet

I hava a Java Spark Streaming app (v1.6.1) that saves Spark SQL DataFrames as parquet files that I'm trying to make externally accessible via a Dropwizard web app. Two questions:

1) How to get the output in a form Dropwizard can use it. df.save(path) only accepts String pathnames and df.show() writes to System.out, neither of which is palatable. I'd love to use Spark SQL's Json support directly but don't want to read files to get it. Must I revert to df.javaRDD.foreachPartition() to build something Dropwizard can use as a return type?

2) Must each Dropwizard resource (endpoint) build its own SparkContext, or is it OK to build these at a higher level and reuse them in each endpoint?

Answer (score 0):

No responses so I'll try myself.

There can only be one SparkContext per JVM so the JavaSparkContext must be shared by all end points. So I pass one in via the constructor. Its not yet clear to me whether this poses a syncrhonization risk under higher load than I have now.

This is the best I've managed to date for the first question:

```
JavaRDD<Row> rowRDD = df.javaRDD()
        .mapPartitions(new FlatMapFunction<Iterator<Row>, Row>()
        {
            @Override
            public List<Row> call(Iterator<Row> itr)
                    throws Exception
            {
                List<Row> rowList = new LinkedList<Row>();
                while (itr.hasNext())
                {
                    Row row = itr.next();
                    rowList.add(row);
                }
                return rowList;
            }
        });
final List<Row> rowList = rowRDD.collect();
final StructType types = df.schema();
final String[] names = types.fieldNames();
rowList.add(RowFactory.create(names));
Response r = Response
       .status(200)
       .entity(rowList)
       .build();
return r;
```